# Need an old version of MSP430 DLL V3 package

Tags: msp430

The latest version is not capable with the python-msp-tool, it needs the MSP430_Identify() function which was removed from the latest version of DLL V3.

So anyone can share me with your older version of DLL V3? The original zip file should with the name slac460c.zip, not slac460.zip. And the version number is 3.2.4.5 or less, not 3.2.5.4.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**:
I just find TI has released some older version of MSP430 DLL V3 package, but it seems it is used for developing under windows which all functions were packaged well. What I need is the pure source code that can be made under Linux with a Makefile.

**EDIT**:
I have compiled the latest version of libMSP430.so (3.2.5.4) for Raspberry Pi. To save other guys time, I have posted the file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B01J7KEhxzPCeWI4UUVReUEzeDg/edit).

**EDIT**:
the MSP430_Identify() can be instead by below two functions:
MSP430_OpenDevice and MSP430_GetFoundDevice. You can refer to MspDebug tool, they are using the up-to-date DLL driver.

Comment: Ok, I have modified the python-msp430-tool to fit the latest DLL with the help from python-msp430-tool's author. Thanks to him.

Comment: www.ti.com/lit/sw/slac460c/slac460c.zip Here is the old version code, thanks to mspgcc-user mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

MSP430 V3 is now open-source. You can easily find them in [TI website](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP_Debug_Stack), with all releases.

Comment: The link to processors.wiki.ti.com is dead. Updated page with download links is [MSPDS MSP Debug Stack](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSPDS)